# Joining Hbase Tables With Pig

Tags: hbase, apache-pig, emr

I am trying to join two HBase tables with using Pig on Amazon EMR .

```
Z = join Y by pid, X by id
```

After I run the code above, it throws the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This file system object (hdfs://10.116.57.150:9000) does not support access to the request path 'hbase://player_derived' You possibly called FileSystem.get(conf) when you should have called FileSystem.get(uri, conf) to obtain a file system supporting your path.
```

Is there any ideas what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this the full stack trace you have? Which Pig version do you use?